# Error in posting products sold and incorrect result of available stock

Tags: mysql

These are the most important tables to get the desired result:

Records: `tbl_order`

| id_order | id_enterprise | id_branch_office | code_unique | title_product | model | size | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | X | null | 10 |
| 2 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | XL | null | 3 |
| 3 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | null | RED | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | null | HOLA | null | null | null | RED | 3 |

Records: `tbl_stock_product`

| id_stock_product | id_enterprise | id_branch_office | code_unique | title_product | model | size | color | item_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | X | null | 100 |
| 2 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | X | null | 1000 |
| 3 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | XL | null | 500 |
| 4 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | null | RED | 10 |
| 4 | null | 1 | HOL | MDLX1 | null | null | null | 300 |

It should be noted that the `model, size, color` columns can be with data or empty depending on the type of product. What is required is the unique code of the product and to whom it belongs, it can be just a company(`id_enterprise`) or branch(`id_branch_office`).

With the following query I have achieved almost everything, the only problem is total_sales and stock:

```
select office_establishment,
       office_tradename,
       code_unique,
       model,
       size,
       color,
       sum(item_total) as item_total,
       sum(quantity)   as quantity,
       sum(stock)      as stock
from (
         SELECT bo.establishment                          AS office_establishment,
                bo.tradename                              AS office_tradename,
                sp.code_unique,
                sp.model,
                sp.size,
                sp.color,
                item_total,
                SUM(ifnull(odr.quantity, 0))              AS quantity,
                item_total - sum(ifnull(odr.quantity, 0)) as stock
         FROM tbl_stock_product sp
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac
                            ON sp.id_enterprise = ac.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_enterprise ent ON sp.id_enterprise = ent.id_enterprise
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_branch_office bo ON sp.id_branch_office = bo.id_branch_office
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr on odr.id_product = sp.id_stock_product
         WHERE ac.id_user = 2
         GROUP BY ent.establishment, bo.establishment, bo.tradename, sp.code_unique, sp.model, sp.size, sp.color,
                  sp.id_stock_product, sp.item_total
     ) t
group by office_establishment, office_tradename, code_unique, model, size, color
```

The problems:

- `t.quantity AS  total_sales`:

  - I am subtracting the same sales from the other results, despite having a different size, color or model.
  - When there are no sales records in the tbl_order table, it does not show anything, ideally it would show 0.
- `SUM(t.item_total) - t.quantity AS stock`

  - When there are no sales records in the `tbl_order` table, it does not show anything,Ideally, it would be to re-display the total available products by saying: `SUM(t.item_total) AS item_total`

And what is affecting this problem is the following conditions passed to the `tbl_order` table:

```
                LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr
                    ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique
                    AND (sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
                    AND sp.model = odr.model
                    AND sp.size = odr.size
                    AND sp.color = odr.color
```

On investigation I found the following: `MySQL` will not be able to distinguish between a column that is `NULL` considering that I tried the following, but I still have the same problem:

```
        LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr
            ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique
            AND (sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
            AND ((sp.model IS NULL OR odr.model IS NULL) OR sp.model = odr.model)
            AND ((sp.size IS NULL OR odr.size IS NULL) OR sp.size = odr.size)
            AND ((sp.color IS NULL OR odr.color IS NULL) OR sp.color = odr.color)
```

Desired result:

| code_unique | model | size | color | item_total | total_sales | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOLA | null | X | null | 1100 | 10 | 1090 |
| HOLA | null | XL | null | 500 | 3 | 497 |
| HOLA | null | null | RED | 10 | 3 | 7 |
| HOL | null | null | null | 300 | 0 | 300 |

Testing: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiz9PeZ9SPM5jWVkmK4aR2/4

Comment: fyi your fiddle doesn't work (cant run). also, i'm not sure what with those `id_branch_office` and `id_enterprise`, are they required in the desired result? perhaps you can [reduce the example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a bit?

Comment: @BagusTesa In my version 5.2.0 of mysql on my server it works, I don't know why it doesn't work there, but I still uploaded it because of the tables issue. If necessary, these two IDs refer to whether that product is held by the parent company or by the branch, therefore, it is necessary for the inventory.

Comment: No, the link to the fiddle that you provided fails when you run it even if you set the version to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: @Booboo This line generates said error, maybe an alternative or you can make a similar approach, since the idea is being proposed in my query and after that verify the problem that I am presenting
 `max(sp.item_total) over (PARTITION BY id_stock_product) AS item_total`

Comment: @Booboo If you realize that line is in charge of adding the values of that column only of the repeated products

Comment: @Booboo Upadate: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiz9PeZ9SPM5jWVkmK4aR2/4

Comment: There was a MariaDB 5.2, but not MySQL.  Check again.

Comment: `OVER...PARTITION BY` requires MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: @RickJames I already corrected that detail look at the update: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiz9PeZ9SPM5jWVkmK4aR2/4

Answer (score 0):

First, some critiques.

- Get rid of `id_enterprise`.  Instead have `id_branch=0` meaning "enterprise".
- The `GROUP BY` does not include all the non-aggregate columns; I am surprised that you did not get hit with "only full group by".
- SUMming MAXes does not make sense.
- One place that a "product" is the combo of `code_unique` and location.  Another place you imply that color, etc help distinguish.
- `OR` makes most index usage impossible.  So do function calls.

Then a possible flaw:

```
LEFT JOIN x  ON ...
    WHERE ...
```

The `ON` should say how they are related.  The `WHERE` should do filtering.  But, the `WHERE` can test for NULL to decide whether you do or do not want rows of the "righthand" table even when the `ON` fails to match.

A guess at the answer.

- Don't use `LEFT` when it is not called for.
- Since you seem to be filtering on `sp` and `odr`.  See if it makes sense to write it this way:

  ```
  FROM sp
  JOIN odr ON ...
  [LEFT] JOIN ((other tables))
  WHERE ((the filtering and any IS NULLs for the other tables))
  ```

**More**

- I'm pretty sure you should not include `sp.item_total` in the inner`GROUP BY`.  Perhaps you should get rid of that `GROUP BY`, instead, have `SELECT DISTINCT`.
- `SUM(IFNULL(x, 0))` can be simplified to `SUM(x)`.
- Because of `WHERE ac.user=2`, the `LEFT JOIN ac` is really `INNER JOIN`.
- The query *may* perform better if `tbl_access` had an index _starting with `id_user`.

Comment: Upadate: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiz9PeZ9SPM5jWVkmK4aR2/4